# How to make branches readonly in gitolite2?

Tags: git, configuration, authorization, gitolite

How can I declare branches readonly in gitolite v2?

My current configuration is:

```
@group1 = user1 user2
@group2 = user3

repo xxx
    R          = @group1  # should make everything readonly per default
    RW  fix    = @group1  # this can be pushed and created
    RW+        = @group2  # for the admin
```

But everyone can push everywhere.

---

2 more cases - as user2 I am locked out here (what is correct):

```
repo xxx
    R          = @group1  # should make everything readonly per default
    RW+        = @group2  # for the admin
```

Now I can push *master*, which shouldn't be:

```
repo xxx
    R          = @group1  # should make everything readonly per default
    RW  fix    = @group1  # this can be pushed and created
    RW+        = @group2  # for the admin
```

I replaced *fix* with *^refs/heads/fix* but that changes nothing.

Comment: Are you using gitolite v2 or v3?

Comment: Considering V2 basic access (http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/exbac.html) you config should work. Is there any chance the address used by everyone is one bypassing gitolite completely? as in http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/sts.html#ssh_troubleshooting_common_ssh_problems_ and http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/sts.html#stsapp5_

Comment: Just made the tests. It's definitly gitolite I'm talking to - I also can see the access (and successful push) in the logs.

Comment: Ok. Next stop, are you using the right ssh "account" (public/private key) when pushing to repo xxx? What is the ssh address you are using? What is your `~/.ssh/config` file content?

Comment: (And any chance you can try it with a GitoliteV3 installation?)

Comment: I'm using the right keys etc. Seems that the the auth-sys is working - but my configuration is wrong. Or there is a bug. V3 would be a lot of work I guess (and I could not use the Debian version anymore).

Comment: Note: gitolite V3 isn't a lot of work. And there is no "Debian" version: gitolite is just a bunch of perl scripts. Simply `git clone https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite` and you are done. You are ready to install it to the directory of your choice, like I did in https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh

Comment: Just to cover everything, can you try with `RW  fix$    = @group1` (`$` at the end)?

Comment: Also can you try to replace the groups by the user names? To see if that changes anything?